# NodeJS: stdin text not egal

Tags: node.js

I use `process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');`
But when i listen a event `'data'`, the text isn't egal.

```
process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
  if (text === 'q') console.log('ouiiiiiiiiii');
  else console.log(text);
});
```

I type 'q' but don't display "ouiiiiiiiii", and the text is q... but the `text === 'q'` is to false, why ? thanks

I think it's due to the encoding, but i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, call `process.stdin.resume()` before you setup your callback on stdin. Also, make sure to convert your `text` variable to a string, as I believe it's a `Buffer` object.

So, something like this should work:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
 if (text.toString().trim() === 'q') {
   console.log('ouiiiiiiiiii');
 } else {
   console.log(text.toString());
 }
});
```